# Is the AWS Textract API configurable?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-textract

I want to extract structured text from PDF contracts with [AWS Textract](https://aws.amazon.com/textract/).

Is the service configurable? For example, can I set the minimum vertical blank space the system uses to split paragraphs?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

No, Amazon Textract is not configurable. It is a managed service that is meant to work "as is" without detailed settings.

Available actions are shown on: [Actions - Amazon Textract](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/textract/latest/dg/API_Operations.html)